# Stuck in logic trying to match pattern?

Tags: php, math, logic, combinations, permutation

I am running a script based on exetime and exetime is saved in database in the format of following.

```
* * * * * *
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
```

Now I need to check exetime with current

> M.H.DofM.MofY.DofW.Y

each field can have two possibilies , it could be respective field or it could be a "*" . what will be the best way two check this pattern with all combination with each field having 2 possibilities.

Comment: I would say regexp :D

Comment: Can one regex check all possibilities ? @kaldoran

Comment: I think so, I'm creating it right now ;)

Comment: [cron expression parser](https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression)

Comment: My answer is done ^^ dont hesitate to validate or upvote :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regexp I think :

```
([0-5]?[0-9]|\*)\.([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]|\*)\.([1-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1]|\*)\.([0-9]|1[0-2]|\*)\.([1-7]|\*)\.(19[0-9][0-9]|2[0-9]{3}|3000|\*)
```

Let's explain this one part by part, the `|` equals to the "and" of my explain; all the part are separate by `\.` which is the "."

```
([0-5]?[0-9]|\*)
```

Will match all number from 0 to 59 or `*`
This ( as the others ) will allow you to use `00`

```
([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]|\*)
```

Will match all number from 0 to 19 and from 20 to 23 or `*`

```
([1-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1]|\*)
```

Will match all number from 0 to 29 and from 30 to 31 or `*`

```
([0-9]|1[0-2]|\*)
```

Easy one; from 0 to 9 or from 10 to 12 or `*`

```
([1-7]|\*)
```

Match 1 to 7 or `*`

```
(19[0-9][0-9]|2[0-9]{3}|3000|\*)
```

Match from 1900 to 1999 and from 2000 to 2999 and 3000 or `*`

Here is an example :
https://regex101.com/r/Orlp3o/2

I let you test some more ;)

Well, I edit my answer in order to add @Mark Baker one, 
https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression

Now you can choose which one you want to use ;)

Comment: but @kaldoran I want to match my current cron time format with saved cron time format and it should also validate the * format if found.

Comment: It does both, if the saved format is for example `*.*.*.*.*.*` it will match, same as if it's `0.19.31.12.7.3000` for example.